# hash code HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I am trying to learn Java. The Eric Roberts text, "The Art and Science of Java" has a programming assignment where we simulate a flight booking console. I wanted to 'class it up' by using a City class where just a City String would do. It only has one field, `name`, which is a String, but I am trying to learn how to use classes.

Anyway, so then I had to override the equals method in the City class to avoid getting duplicates. So then I had to override the hashCode method.

Now my `HashMap<City,ArrayList<Flight>>` isn't working. It can't find certain values and it still permits duplicate keys.

My City `equals` and `hashCode` overrides are as follows. Can anybody see why my HashMap is going wrong?

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( this == that ) return true;
    if ( !( that instanceof City) ) return false;
    City aThat = (City) that;
    return (name == aThat.name );
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: The problem is how you compare String variables: "name == aThat.name". By using "==", you are just comparing the object reference not the content, the same as "this == that". To compare String objects' content, you need the euquals* method of String object. Unlike C++, every object that you can use in code is just the reference  of that object and there is no operator overloading in Java either.

Answer (score 3):

For object comparation use `equals()` instead of `==` , cause `==` compares reference values to determine if they are pointing to the same object.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    //more code
    return (name.equals(aThat.name) );
}
```

By the way your `hashCode()` it's also bad cause your `name` could be null and you will get a `NullPointerException`.

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

And at last advice , i don't recommend you to use as a key in a `hash structure` like your hashMap `mutable objects` cause its `hashCode()` will change and unexpected behaviour can happen. It's better to use `inmutable objects` as key. If City class is inmutable then it's ok, but if it's not then change it.

Comment: `==` compares reference values *to determine* if they are pointing to the same *object.* -1 for sloppiness.

Comment: @EJP sorry you got it right! my english is bad

Answer (score -1):

When checking if values of objects are the same dont use ==. Instead use .equals, In your equals method change == to .equals,

For instance

```
String str1 = "Foo bar";
String str2 = "Foo bar";
str1 == str2 // not always true!
str1.equals(str2) // very true

@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ( this == that ) return true;
    if ( !( that instanceof City) ) return false;
    City aThat = (City) that;
    return (name.equals(aThat.name) );   // <--- see edit 
}
```

Comment: -1 for incorrect description of usage of ==, and removal of actually correct line from OP's source code.  There are valid use for == when comparing object reference, and the line in OP's code is precisely a valid case.  Normally when we implements `equals()`, the very first thing to check is whether the incoming obj ref is referring same object as `this`, if so, they are equals and we can skip all those subsequent heavy checking.

Comment: Well I didnt want to go into GREAT detail of how == works as he is obviously a newcomer to java, im sure he/she is capable of looking into it further if they would like. And I dont belive .equals on a String object should be considered heavy checking.

Comment: As I said : 1. The statement 'should never use ==' is simply incorrect, nothing to argue.  2. Check of input obj ref with this is simply the very very normal practice of implementing `equals()`, asking OP to remove that line is simply misleading.  I think there are better way to simplify the answer, rather that giving incorrect statements.

Comment: You are correct I overlooked the first sentence of my response.

Comment: Removing the `this == that` optimization is a bad idea (empirically)

Comment: Your line `str1 == str2 // not always true!` is, well, not true.

Comment: removed -1 for the main criticial problems in answer resolved.  To elaborate on Davaid's comment: both str1 and str2 is referring to a string literal, which is going to be the same instance in string pool, which is always true in this case.  Suggest @ns47731 to change the answer to be something like `String str1= new String("Foo bar");` which can better demonstrate the idea